# Dynamic control over cache max age at request time in Django

Tags: django, cache-control

In Django I can use something like this to [manage cache's max-age](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/cache/#controlling-cache-using-other-headers) for a request:

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_control

@cache_control(max_age=3600)
def my_view(request):
    # ...
```

How can I set a different `max_age` value *inside* the view function so that it can depend on what the `request` content is?

Example:

```
def my_view(request):
    if is_good_to_cache(request):
        # set max_age to 36000
    else:
        # set max_age to 42 
    # ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `cache_control` is [taking advantage of `patch_cache_control` internally](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/decorators/cache.py#L34), it's OK to directly put:

```
from django.utils.cache import patch_cache_control

def my_view(request):
    if is_good_to_cache(request):
        max_age = 36000
    else:
        max_age = 42 
    resp = render(...)
    patch_cache_control(resp, max_age=max_age)
    return resp
```